# por que o meu comando print não funciona?

Tags: python, python-3.x

o meu comando print não funciona de jeito nenhum,quando eu uso ele no pycharm não funciona e quando eu faço um script com o idle também não funciona,mas quando eu faço com o prompt do python funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o script faz as perguntas mas não mostra a respostas usando o print.

Comment: Caro usuário, tire a imagem e coloque o seu código fonte para melhorar a pesquisa futura de usuários com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Você está fazendo uma atribuicao na linha

```
print = (nome,idade,peso)
```

o correto é

```
print(nome,idade,peso)
```

Comment: ata muito obrigado pela ajuda,eu não consegui entender o por que de não estar funcionando muito obrigado